# names of a dataset returns NULL- R version 3.2.4 Revised-Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a small issue regarding a dataset I am using. Suppose I have a dataset called `mergedData2` defined using those command lines from a subset of `mergedData`:

```
mergedData=rbind(test_set,training_set)
lookformean<-grep("mean()",names(mergedData),fixed=TRUE)
lookforstd<-grep("std()",names(mergedData),fixed=TRUE)
varsofinterests<-sort(c(lookformean,lookforstd))
mergedData2<-mergedData[,c(1:2,varsofinterests)]
```

If I do `names(mergedData2)`, I get:

```
 [1] "volunteer_identifier" "type_of_experiment"    
 [3] "body_acceleration_mean()-X" "body_acceleration_mean()-Y"                     
 [5] "body_acceleration_mean()-Z"  "body_acceleration_std()-X"
```

(I takes this 6 first names as MWE but I have a vector of 68 names)

Now, suppose I want to take the average of each of the measurements per `volunteer_identifier` and `type_of_experiment`. For this, I used a combination of `split` and `lapply`:

```
mylist<-split(mergedData2,list(mergedData2$volunteer_identifier,mergedData2$type_of_experiment))
average_activities<-lapply(mylist,function(x) colMeans(x))
average_dataset<-t(as.data.frame(average_activities))
```

As `average_activities` is a list, I converted it into a data frame and transposed this data frame to keep the same format as `mergedData` and `mergedData2`. The problem now is the following: when I call `names(average_dataset)`, it returns `NULL` !! But, more strangely, when I do:`head(average_dataset)` ; it returns :

```
 volunteer_identifier type_of_experiment body_acceleration_mean()-X body_acceleration_mean()-Y 
                    1                  1    0.2773308                -0.01738382
                    2                  1    0.2764266                -0.01859492
                    3                  1    0.2755675                -0.01717678
                    4                  1    0.2785820                -0.01483995
                    5                  1    0.2778423                -0.01728503
                    6                  1    0.2836589                -0.01689542
```

This is just a small sample of the output, to say that the names of the variables are there. So why `names(average_dataset)` returns `NULL` ?

Thanks in advance for your reply, best

EDIT: Here is an MWE for mergedData2:

```
 volunteer_identifier type_of_experiment body_acceleration_mean()-X body_acceleration_mean()-Y
   1             2                  5                  0.2571778                -0.02328523
   2             2                  5                  0.2860267                -0.01316336
   3             2                  5                  0.2754848                -0.02605042
   4             2                  5                  0.2702982                -0.03261387
   5             2                  5                  0.2748330                -0.02784779
   6             2                  5                  0.2792199                -0.01862040
 body_acceleration_mean()-Z body_acceleration_std()-X body_acceleration_std()-Y body_acceleration_std()-Z
1                -0.01465376                -0.9384040                -0.9200908                -0.6676833
2                -0.11908252                -0.9754147                -0.9674579                -0.9449582
3                -0.11815167                -0.9938190                -0.9699255                -0.9627480
4                -0.11752018                -0.9947428                -0.9732676                -0.9670907
5                -0.12952716                -0.9938525                -0.9674455                -0.9782950
6                -0.11390197                -0.9944552                -0.9704169                -0.9653163
 gravity_acceleration_mean()-X gravity_acceleration_mean()-Y gravity_acceleration_mean()-Z
1                     0.9364893                    -0.2827192                     0.1152882
2                     0.9274036                    -0.2892151                     0.1525683
3                     0.9299150                    -0.2875128                     0.1460856
4                     0.9288814                    -0.2933958                     0.1429259
5                     0.9265997                    -0.3029609                     0.1383067
6                     0.9256632                    -0.3089397                     0.1305608
 gravity_acceleration_std()-X gravity_acceleration_std()-Y gravity_acceleration_std()-Z
1                   -0.9254273                   -0.9370141                   -0.5642884
2                   -0.9890571                   -0.9838872                   -0.9647811
3                   -0.9959365                   -0.9882505                   -0.9815796
4                   -0.9931392                   -0.9704192                   -0.9915917
5                   -0.9955746                   -0.9709604                   -0.9680853
6                   -0.9988423                   -0.9907387                   -0.9712319
```

My duty is to get this average_dataset (which is a dataset which contains the average value for each physical quantity (column 3 and onwards) for each volunteer and type of experiment (e.g 1 1 mean1 mean2 mean3...mean68
2 1 mean1 mean2 mean3...mean68, etc)

After this I will have to export it as a txt file (so I think using write.table with row.names=F, and col.names=T). Note that for now, if I do this and import the dataset generated using read.table, I don't recover the names of the columns of the dataset; even while specifying col.names=T.

Comment: The immediate problem seems to be caused by transposing the data.frame with `t()`. For example, `tmp <- t(iris); names(tmp); class(tmp)` seems to reproduce the error. The data.frame has been converted to a matrix by transposing. Matrices don't have `names()` but they do have `colnames()` and `rownames()`. Better to find another way and not use `t()` on data.frames.

Comment: @bdemarest, thanks for your answer. However, is there a way to define these variables names that I shew on the last output as names of the column of a dataset ? Thanks

Comment: It will much easier to help if you can provide a minimal, reproducible example. Create a small example dataset to include in your code. Then show the result you want your code to produce. For example, I can't see the structure of `mergedData2`, so I can't follow what is going wrong with `split`, `lapply`, `t`. Finally, the help files `?split` suggest using `unsplit` so you may want to look at that.